# How do I link a UIButton to my data object? (iPhone / Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I'm new to iPhone dev. My app is dynamically creating buttons, following from my data model. The model isn't just a simple list; it's a tree. I need some way to correlate a created button to that data model, so that when the button is clicked I know what part of the model it corresponds to.

On Windows, most UI controls have a "tag" field where you could put custom data. Using a similar pattern, what I'd like to do on the iPhone is this:

```
- (void)createMyButton:(MyModel*)foo
{
  UIButton* button = <insert creation code here>
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleCreatedButtonTouch:) ...];
  button.tag = foo;
}

- (void)handleCreatedButtonTouch:(id)sender
{
  UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
  MyModel* foo = (MyModel*)(button.tag);
  [foo userTouchedMyButton];
}
```

I can't find any mention of such a field in the Apple documentation. How do you iPhone gurus do this? Again, I don't have any simple way of indexing into my data model, and doing an enumeration over the entire data model to find a match seems very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew,

UI elements in the iPhone SDK have a `tag` property similar to what you are describing.  If you're looking to use button.tag, then you can do so out of the box.

The only change to your pseudo-code would be in your `handleCreatedButtonTouch:` method.  the line:

```
MyModel* foo = (MyModel *)(button.tag);
```

would try to cast the `tag` property to a `MyModel` object.  You would probably want to create an initializer in MyModel to that handles the lookup, such as:

```
MyModel *foo = [[MyModel alloc] initFromButtonWithTag:[sender tag]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, thanks! I looked through the documentation again and I find this under the MacOS X documentation for "NSControl" but not for the iPhone's "UIControl". What's up with that? Is the documentation off?

Comment: Sometimes you have to dig pretty deep into the documentation to find what you are looking for.  `UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`, and `UIControl` inherits from `UIView`, and `UIView` has the `tag` property.  You can visualize it as: `UIControl : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject`, where `UIView` supports `tag`.

Comment: why create a new object? what if one wants to just pass in an existing object?